# Extract data from another excel in power query advanced editor

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I'm trying to extract the data from another excel file, but I tried to make it dynamic.

This is the context so I'm extracting data with a survey for different cities and the questions are the same but the data is different in each city, so I'm trying to create visualisations for each city but just replacing the data in the file, so this data is exported as a file we can call it "results-city.xlsx" and my goal is just placing this document with another with the same name and columns but obviously different responses in each column so I'm trying to use power query and the advanced editor and this is my formula but is not getting success also the path will be dynamic that's the reason I included folder in the formula.

Help please - how to achieve this?

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\iotal\OneDrive\Desktop\stack\folder\results-city.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Update 2:

**Example of data:**

[File with data city 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-NEwPzlfSVcTRFpkhkUOPnomdC9Ps0-9p_6_zPXNDwM/edit?usp=sharing)

So here is an example with the data from two cities [File with data city 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmp062c6Apijda1YyqdPxrb-MY7k_ra3Tj5PB0Mmnw4/edit?usp=sharing), when I tried to use the formula the power query don't import the data to Excel.

**My desired output** is have the data imported in a sheet in Excel that doesn't mind which of the two is in the folder but can be updated.

This is my desired output with images:

Image 1 is the first data that I will import:

[image]

And the second image is when I replace the data for city2 should look like this just replacing the file for another one with the same name

[image]

And what is not working is the formula that doesn't import to a sheet the data as a table

When I replace the file from city1 for the one from city2 I got this error:

[image]

Comment: What part is not getting success ? Post example of your data, desired output and what is not happening properly

Comment: The part that I'm not extracting the data to the sheet

Comment: ready the data example in updated 1

Comment: By dynamic you mean you want to be able to update the folder name and vary the location of the source file - so you're looking for a way to specify the folder parameter in question yes?

Comment: exactly @JB-007

Comment: I updated the post with all the info

Comment: see if below works for you - have linked a file per gif to make implementation easier.  ta--Ahh looks like I was late to the party - trying to make it pretty with extra dynamic features/gif etc. lol:) so long as you found something that resolves the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, something like this will combine all tabs in all xlsx files in a specified hardcoded directory

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Alternatively, give a cell a range name, like **path** in excel and put your filepath in that cell, like **C:\temp\a.xlsx**

Then in powerquery, use that range name in place of hardcoding the file name like

```
let location= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="path"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(location), null, true),                           
...
```

this second alternative assumes that the tab name is constant. Otherwise I recommend the first method

You can combine the two alternatives if you want

Comment: When I import the last column appears the sheet is possible to not doing that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question. If there are columns you don't want then right click and remove them

Answer (score 0):

To make the folder location dynamic with respect to a cell with named range "file_path" (B2, below/ [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gbcovglfU0Ga0Czazw?e=vYIxCk)), modify an ordinary power query data import for one of the files/locations (here, "C:\temp\Folder1\File1.txt") as follows:

**ordinary power query:**

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\Folder1\File1.txt"),[Delimiter="   ", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

**updated power query:**

```
let
    MyFolder = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="file_path"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(MyFolder),[Delimiter="  ", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

i.e. file name `XYZ` in [Name ="`XYZ`"] replaced with variable MyFolder, defined as follows:

```
MyFolder = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="file_path"]}[Content][Column1]
```

[image: Exampe file - linked]

---

(optional)

Include VB code to refresh query every time the drop down list changes in the cell with named range ("file_path") (i.e. cell B2 above gif) - as follows:
*(you don't have to do this - you could just as easily make the query refreshable periodically via the properties UI associated with the query, for instance)..*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("file_path")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Calculate
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - dynamic_file").Refresh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Calculate
    
    
End If


End Sub
```

---

Kudos to Cristiano Galvão ([here](https://excelturbo.com.br/dynamic-folders-excel-power-query)) for more details RE: dynamic links per above.

ta

Comment: the first answer was more close to what I need

Comment: glad to hear you got the answer you need.  br,