# Replacing excel file for a new one with the same name and columns using Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, updates, data-import

I'm trying to import 4 different excel documents with Power Query in Excel. So I'm using the formula at the end of the post. To give you context I have a survey for 8 cities so I'm trying to create multiple graphs and charts, so the survey is applied to every city and obviusly in each city I have different ammounts of data(Rows depending on the number of people who participate) so to avoid creating multiple documents and repiting creating graphs and save time I want to create a file using power query to be able and just copy and pasting to replace the data from one city for the second and then the third.

Example of data: File with [data city 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-NEwPzlfSVcTRFpkhkUOPnomdC9Ps0-9p_6_zPXNDwM/edit?usp=sharing) So here is an example with the data from two cities files with [data city 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmp062c6Apijda1YyqdPxrb-MY7k_ra3Tj5PB0Mmnw4/edit?usp=sharing), when I tried to use the formula the power query import the data to excel but when I replace that file with the one from the city 2 appears an error.

**My desired output** is have the data imported in a sheet in excel that doesn't mind which of the city files is in the folder but that update every time that I replace the excel file from other city.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\results-city.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: use File.Contents() to get the name of the file, so when you replace it each month, it pulls the right file name

Comment: @horseyride could you show me how?

Comment: See answer to your other question

Comment: which one I have 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271596/extract-data-from-another-excel-in-power-query-advanced-editor